# How to export everything from WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, export

I have a lot of files, photos and chats on WhatsApp. Today, I learned that although WhatsApp backs these up regularly, it's not actually possible for me to export my own data. The only thing I found is to click individually on single messages, and either copy the text, or click downlod photo/video, on the phone. I also tried WhatsApp Web, but it doesn't actually sync my chat history after a few weeks. I tried exporting individual chats with media included, but the messages and media are not actually included in the export, apart from a few messages. I also saw that forwarded meesages are not even displayed in my device gallery, or folders on my phone. Since I have thousands of important photos and chats in WhatsApp, how can I save my data to an external harddrive?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [How to export a large WhatsApp chat with media exactly as it appears on my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213693/44325), [How to export/convert WhatsApp chat to PDF/Excel/HTML?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190505/44325)